# How to create alarm with date, time and repetition for some days(suppose 10 days) which show alert even the phone is reset or lock?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-alarms, repeat

I am creating a reminder application for that i want to create a alarm with date time and number of days repetation. As i am new in android development can any one please help me with this?

[I have check this link](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2013/06/set-alarm-on-specified-datetime-with.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an `AlarmManager` for that. The only thing to take into account is that you need to restart your alarm if your phone is resetted, but you can listen for an `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast message and restart it there.

This guide contains everything you need, there's no need to go trough that here:

[Scheduling Repeating Alarms](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html)

Comment: Hey, thank u. Can pls you tell me how this flow work- the activity to reciver then the alarm screen activity??

Comment: There are thousands of tutorials online about this exact same problem, please follow the link I sent you.